# Javascript - simplifying a bunch of long repetative hide/show functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Things have gotten out of hand for me. What started off as the simplest solution has ballooned to the point where it is no longer manageable. I need to come up with a way to simplify a process.

Currently I have a map with pins denoting specific countries world-wide. As the mouse hovers over a pin, a hidden div appears. When you mouse over another one, the previous div disappears and a new one opens. I started with like 5 of these and it wasn't an issue but I keep getting requests for more and want to manage the script in a different way now.

```
$('#PH1').mouseenter(function () {
$('#BO2').hide();
$('#US2').hide();
$('#UK2').hide();
$('#CH2').hide();
$('#BZ2').hide();
$('#QC2').hide();
$('#OT2').hide();
$('#VA2').hide();
$('#RU2').hide();
$('#JT2').hide();
$('#HK2').hide();
$('#SH2').hide();
$('#BJ2').hide();
$('#XI2').hide();   
$('#BE2').hide();
$('#AT2').hide();
$('#FR2').hide();
$('#MX2').hide();
$('#PH2').show();
});

$('#PH1').click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#mint').click(function () {
$('#PH2').hide();
});
```

In this instance div id #PH1 is the pin, when the mouse enters the div it hides all of the other div's #**2 and displays the one related to #PH1, which is #PH2

This list is repeated for each DIV. Every time I need to add a new DIV I need to make each existing list longer as well as create a new one. How can this process be made much simpler?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the structure of your HTML, understanding how these divs relate to each other in the DOM may lead to a easier more generic way of showing/hiding them

Comment: Please provide your html, as this might be possible using css only, which will give simplicity and speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not a right way to do this, you should use classes for this. But their is a wayaround for this all you need to is add a class add class `ele1` to all `#**1` and `ele2` to all `#**2`:

then

```
$('.ele1').mouseenter(function () {
    $(".ele2").hide();
    var id = this.id;
    var newId = id.substring(0,2)+"2";
    $("#"+newId).show();    
});
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. Thank you for the elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop:

```
var all= ['#BO2', '#US2', '#UK2', '#CH2', '#BZ2', '#QC2', '#OT2', '#VA2', '#RU2', '#JT2', '#HK2', '#SH2', '#BJ2', '#XI2'   , '#BE2', '#AT2', '#FR2', '#MX2', '#PH2']

all.forEach(function (i){
    $(i).hide();
});
```

Comment: This is not what OP has asked for!

Comment: This would work, but still requires a lot of transcription. A more elegant solution using 'this' was posted below. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 1):

Use a class selector on all of the DIVs you want to hide/show instead of an ID.

First, add a shared class to all DIVs so we target all of them by class.

`HTML: class="hidden-divs"`

`jQuery: $('.hidden-divs').hide();`

Then show the relevant DIV.

`$('#PH2').show();`

Using your first example, it would look like this:

`$('#PH1').mouseenter(function () {
  $('.hidden-divs').hide();
  $('#PH2').show();
});`

Comment: But anyway OP has to write the function `mouseenter` for every `#**1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to hide multiple divs if you can select them. For example, suppose you have a common class ".map_divs" on all your divs, you could easily do:

```
$(".map_divs").hide();
```

On a side-note, you could solve all this on CSS, using `:hover`. For example:

```
.map_divs:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the div's yourself (if it is not generated by a library) I would do it like this.

Add a common class to all your divs. Then on each div, add a `data` attribtue to the related id.

```
<div class="pin" id="PH1" data-rel="PH2"></div>
```

Then you can have a simple function like this:

```
$(".pin").mouseenter(function() {
    var relatedId = $(this).data("rel");
    $(".pin[id$='2']").hide(); // Hide all pins with id ending in 2
    $("#" + relatedId).show() //show PH2
})
```

Comment: This is basically the same answer to the one I ended up using. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using classes might be a better option here. You can then just attach the mouseenter event on document ready to all pins. This will work for an infinite number of pins too.

```js
$('.pin').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.popup').removeClass('show');
    var id = this.id.split('_')[1];
    $('#popup_' + id).addClass('show');
});
```

```css
.pin {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:red;
}

.popup {
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.popup.show {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pin_1" class="pin"></div>
<div id="popup_1" class="popup"></div>
<div id="pin_2" class="pin"></div>
<div id="popup_2" class="popup"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is basically identical to the answer I ended up using. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If your div element is ordered like below, you can get the same result using css only, which will increase speed and overall experience (especially on phones and tablets).

When "hover" the yellow squares, the popup will be visibible even when "hover" the popup.

```css
.pin {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:red;
}

.popup {
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.pin:hover + .popup {
    display:block;
}

.pin.type2 {
    background-color:yellow;
}

.pin.type2:hover .popup {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pin_1" class="pin"></div>
<div id="popup_1" class="popup"></div>
<div id="pin_2" class="pin"></div>
<div id="popup_2" class="popup"></div>

<div id="pin_3" class="pin type2"><div id="popup_3" class="popup"></div></div>
<div id="pin_4" class="pin type2"><div id="popup_4" class="popup"></div></div>
```